# Just squashed with git rebase, now can't push that squash to remote, says everything is up to date

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I needed to squash the last 2 commits into one, which I did successfully with `git rebase -i HEAD~2`. Problem is now when I got to push with `git push origin master` I get : Everything up-to-date

Thanks for any help

Comment: Were either or both of the last two commits previously pushed?

Comment: yes I pushed both, then realized I need to rebase, at this point I destroyed what I had locally started again with fresh git clone, and rebased, but now when I try to push, it says I'm behind the master branch.  I'm assuming since I essentially got rid of commit by squashing it, it believes I'm behind the master... git gives me headaches

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Squashing locally removes a commit. Git sees that `origin` has the commit that you squashed and tells you you are behind. You have to push your change to `origin`, which requires the `--force` (or `-f` for short) flag to overwrite the history it has on record.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work with

`git push --force origin master`

Comment: [obligatory git debugging flowchart](http://justinhileman.info/article/git-pretty/full/)